# Corda - FiberDeserializationChecker Error handling

Tags: java, corda

Flow execution between `account A on Node A` and the responder are 2 members i.e. `account B on Node B` and `Node C` is executing successfully, but it throws the tones of warnings and the error related to `FiberDeserializationChecker` at the end of flow execution.

```
[ERROR] 13:42:00+0530 [FiberDeserializationChecker] interceptors.FiberDeserializationChecker. - Encountered unrestorable checkpoint! - java.lang.NullPointerException
Serialization trace:
childProgressTrackers (net.corda.core.utilities.ProgressTracker)
progressTracker (com.blockchain.corda.flows.initiator.UpdateInitiatorFlow)
this$0 (com.blockchain.corda.flows.initiator.UpdateInitiatorFlow$2)
second (kotlin.Pair)_allStepsCache (net.corda.core.utilities.ProgressTracker)
progressTracker(com.blockchain.corda.flows.initiator.CreateInitiatorFlow)logic (net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl) [errorCode=7sftly, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.5/7sftly]
```

***The Flow execution is as follows:***

Triggers the `CreateInitiatorFlow`, this will create the state as per the logic.
On successful creation of state we are calling the `subFlow` i.e `UpdateInitiatorFlow`, which will update few details in another state.
After the successful execution of `subflow` it returns back to the main flow and returns the response but with the above error.

**Corda version: 4.5

DB: PostgreSql**

***To handle the warnings Annotations used are:***

```
@Suppress(names = "unused") 
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Suspendable
```

***Is there any way to handle the warnings and the error related to the*** `FiberDeserializationChecker`?

Answer (score 0):

Putting some pointers as discussed on Cordaledger Slack.

The errors are related to the suspension of flows i.e. flow checkpointing. Certain resources (Closable) cannot be restored when flows are resumed and hence should be separated in a separated and put in a separate method that is not annotated with `@Suspendable`.

Certain custom schema has been defined which could have caused the issue since the problem doesn't come when the custom schema is commented out. A recommendation to get over this is to add logic related to accessing the schema in a separate method which is not `@Suspendable` annotated.